# Biometrics with React-Native with external fingerprint scanner(secugen, futronics)

Tags: javascript, react-native, fingerprint, biometrics

I will like to know if anyone has done a biometric application with React-native.
I want to know what you've done to allow a user scan with an external fingerprint scanner(SecuGen Hamster plus, futronics) and have access to the image on the device.
I am using React-Native not Java. 
Any head-up will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: If you're not asking experts in java, then you need to remove that tag.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?